# Issue with onClick listener and context within a customAdapter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an ArrayAdapter that allows a user to access individual `TextView` fields which link to the internet, googlemaps, etc. I am unable to resolve an issue in which the error states

> Cannot resolve method 'startActivity (android.content.Intent).

After looking through quite a few posts on here, I've established that it's an issue with `context`, I'm not sure how I get this from the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
package com.example.stuart.listitemviewtest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class AttractionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
     public AttractionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Attraction> attractions) {
    super(context, 0, attractions);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    // Get the {@link currentAttraction} object located at this position in the list
    final Attraction currentAttraction = (Attraction) getItem(position);

    final TextView attractionName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.attraction_name);
    attractionName.setText(currentAttraction.getmName());
    attractionName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("attraction Name", "the name of attraction: " + currentAttraction.getmName());
        }
    });
    TextView attractionURL =(TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.attraction_URL);
    attractionURL.setText(currentAttraction.getmWebAddress());
    attractionURL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

    //get web address
    Log.i("Web Address", "The web address is: " +                           currentAttraction.getmWebAddress());


        //load URL in new window
          Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
             intent.setData(Uri.parse(currentAttraction.getmWebAddress()));
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return listItemView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor like this:-

```
  Context mContext;
  public AttractionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Attraction> attractions) {
super(context, 0, attractions);
mContext = context;
}
```

now use mContext before startActivity();

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse(currentAttraction.getmWebAddress()));
         mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: because, getContext() will retrieve the context you passed to super through your constructor. mContext is redundant!!!

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I've got it working! Would you need to make any changes to the code if you use this within a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You need an context to start a new activity,i.e activity context

```
 //load URL in new window
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(currentAttraction.getmWebAddress()));
 (listItemView.getContext()).startActivity(intent);
```